# Ubuntu 23.10 installation failing

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I'm attempting to get a dual boot setup. I created 200gb of free space before starting.

The 23.10.1 install disk boots fine although there are a few errors on the black screen that disappear to be replaced by the start. I go through the installation and everything seems to work until I select restart. Then it sticks on this screen:

[image: errors after restart begins]

If I turn the machine off and on again, it just boots into Windows normally as before. I tried running chkdsk in windows and no errors are reported.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Your provided details show IO errors on device sdc; so you should be checking the health of that drive, and ensuring you have all data backed up correctly as the drive itself maybe failing.  If windows is on that same device, it may also not be safe, as drive disk errors start somewhere & usually expand (*unless circuit failure where it will just stop responding*). Also note `chkdsk` performs a logical check of metadata only (reading a small fraction of 1% of disk); you need to perform physical checks!  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools